# Imagens Para o Produto Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou com um problema, não sei como faço para salvar mais de uma imagens para um produto. Por exemplo, um produto X tem uma imagem de Destaque(que é a que vai aparecer na vitrine), e mais 4 imagens, que vão aparece na pagina de detalhes do produto. Estou tentando salvar as imagens em uma pasta, e salvar apenas o caminho dessas imagens no banco (Boas Práticas). salvar apenas uma imagem na pasta e a URL, no banco eu consigo, não é dificil, agora salvar mais de uma imagem que eu não consigo.

Minha Classe Imagem:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace E_Commerce.Models.Loja
{
    public class Imagem
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public HttpPostedFileBase Arquivo { get; set; }
        public string UrlDaImagem { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Eu sei que no meu produto eu tenho que referenciar a classe imagem. Mas não sei como fazer para salvar essas imagens para o produto. pesquisei na internet, e tudo que eu mais achava, eram exemplos para salvar apenas uma imagem na pasta, e a URL, no banco, encontrei também, um exemplo de upload de multiplos arquivos, porém, não salvava o caminho no banco.(Macorrati)

Minha Classe Produto:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace E_Commerce.Models
{
    public class ProdutoTeste
    {

        public ProdutoTeste()
        {
            this.Imagens = new List<Imagem>();
        }
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
        public decimal PrecoDeAtacado { get; set; }
        public decimal PrecoDeVarejo { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Categoria")]
        public int Idcategoria { get; set; }
        public virtual Categoria Categoria { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Imagem> Imagens { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Minha Controller, salva apenas uma imagem, mas meu protudo tem mais de uma imagem. Essa controller abaixo. é um exemplo de como salvar uma imagem na pasta, e a URL no banco. a controller para o produto eu ainda não fiz, justamente pq não sei como salvar mais de uma imagem.

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Create(FotoDaColecao fotoDaColecao)
        {

            string nomeDoArquivo = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fotoDaColecao.Arquivo.FileName);
            string extensao = Path.GetExtension(fotoDaColecao.Arquivo.FileName);
            nomeDoArquivo = nomeDoArquivo + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssffff") + extensao;
            fotoDaColecao.UrlDaImagem = "~/Imagens/Produtos/" + nomeDoArquivo;
            nomeDoArquivo = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Imagens/Produtos/"), nomeDoArquivo);
            fotoDaColecao.Arquivo.SaveAs(nomeDoArquivo);
            db.FotosDb.Add(fotoDaColecao);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");



        }
```

Na real eu quero fazer da seguinte maneira:
Vou cadastrar o produto X, e no momento que do cadastrando já quero selecionar suas imagens, para salvar junto.
Eu preciso criar um controller para imagem? Alguém pode ajudar!!

Comment: Basta você pegar todos os arquivos da `FormCollection`...

Comment: Continuo boiando rsrsrsr. sou leigo quando se trata de trabalhar com imagens.

Comment: inclua a sua view na pergunta, como você está fazendo o post para a controller